# search not working in pagination

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i'm working on a website an i have a page showing all the data from my database with pagination all are working fine except for search.when i search like tom it only shows the result from the first page..i have a name of tom in different pages but it only show result where i'm in the current page.

please help me with this..

**class.user.php**

```
<?php

class paginate
{
 private $db;

 function __construct($DB_con)
 {
     $this->db = $DB_con;
    }

    public function dataview($query)
     {
     $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
     $stmt->execute();

     if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
     {
            while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
               ?>
               <tr>
               <td><?php echo $row['user_id']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['password']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['province']; ?></td>

               </tr>
               <?php
            }
     }
     else
     {
            ?>
            <tr>
            <td>Nothing here...</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
     }

 }

 public function paging($query,$records_per_page)
 {
    $starting_position=0;
    if(isset($_GET["page_no"]))
    {
         $starting_position=($_GET["page_no"]-1)*$records_per_page;
    }
    $query2=$query." limit $starting_position,$records_per_page";
    return $query2;
 }

 public function paginglink($query,$records_per_page)
 {

    $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    $total_no_of_records = $stmt->rowCount();

    if($total_no_of_records > 0)
    {
        ?><tr><td colspan="4" align="center"><?php
        $total_no_of_pages=ceil($total_no_of_records/$records_per_page);
        $current_page=1;
        if(isset($_GET["page_no"]))
        {
           $current_page=$_GET["page_no"];
        }
        if($current_page!=1)
        {
           $previous =$current_page-1;
           echo "<a href='".$self."?page_no=1'>First</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
           echo "<a href='".$self."?page_no=".$previous."'>Previous</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }
        for($i=1;$i<=$total_no_of_pages;$i++)
        {
        if($i==$current_page)
        {
            echo "<strong><a href='".$self."?page_no=".$i."' style='color:red;text-decoration:none'>".$i."</a></strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<a href='".$self."?page_no=".$i."'>".$i."  </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }
   }
   if($current_page!=$total_no_of_pages)
   {
    $next=$current_page+1;
    echo "<a href='".$self."?page_no=".$next."'>Next</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    echo "<a href='".$self."?page_no=".$total_no_of_pages."'>Last</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
   }
   ?></td></tr><?php
  }
 }
}
```

**jquery/ajax**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#searchme").keyup(function(){

    if( $(this).val() != "")
    {

        $("#data tbody>tr").hide();
        $("#data td:contains-ci('" + $(this).val() + "')").parent("tr").show();
    }
    else
    {

        $("#data tbody>tr").show();
    }
});
});
</script>
```

**index.php**

```
<body>

<div id="table-wrapper" class="table-responsive">
<input type="text" name="search" id="searchme" placeholder="Search...">
    <table id="data" class="table table-striped table-hover">

        <thead>
        <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>Actions</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <?php 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM login";       
    $records_per_page=20;
    $newquery = $paginate->paging($query,$records_per_page);
    $paginate->dataview($newquery);
    $paginate->paginglink($query,$records_per_page);  
    ?>
</tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your question is very long and nobody desire to read and solve it. Make it shorter.

Comment: @mohammad i already updated my question